How to enable Google Analytics DebugView when adding GoogleAnalytics configuration in Next.js 14
I use GoogleAnalytics imported from @next/third-parties/google to include a GA4 property in my Next.js 14.2 webapp.
Unfortunately <GoogleAnalytics gaId="G-MY-ID" /> does not accept a debug_mode parameter and DebugView is not enabled by default. How do I enable the DebugView in this setup?
This is the default setup that I'm using aswell:
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@next/third-parties/google'
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
      <GoogleAnalytics gaId="G-XYZ" />
    </html>
  )
}


Now it's available, you can use it like
<GoogleAnalytics gaId="G-XYZ" debugMode />

